# Animation Bounce property not working in Safari browser

Tags: html, css, animation, keyframe

```css
@keyframes bounce {

    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    20%{
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    60%{
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    40% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
        transform: translateY(-20px);
    }

    80% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
        transform: translateY(-10px);
    }
    100%{
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}

.services-amenities .img-container:hover{
    -webkit-animation:bounce 0.5s;
    animation: bounce 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 text-center box">
            <div class="img-container"><span class="icon icon_breakfast"></span></div>
            <div class="text-uppercase">Complimentary Continental Breakfast</div>
        </div>
```

the following code i have written to get the animation bounce effect to the icons the code is working in the chrome and firefox but it is not working in the safari browser. i have also mentioned the webkit the property.

Comment: I don't think you've posted your full/correct code. There is no `.services-amenities` element in HTML. Is it the parent `div`?

Comment: @harry....sorry i forget to put it yes it is parent div

Comment: I don't think prefixes are required anymore but did you try including `@-webkit-keyframes` also?

Comment: i got the solution check it out  @Harry

Answer (score 0):

```css
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {

    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    20%{
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    60%{
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    40% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
        transform: translateY(-20px);
    }

    80% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
        transform: translateY(-10px);
    }
    100%{
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes bounce{

    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    20%{
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    60%{
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    40% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
        transform: translateY(-20px);
    }

    80% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
        transform: translateY(-10px);
    }
    100%{
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
```

```html
<section class="services-amenities">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 text-center box">
            <div class="img-container"><span class="icon icon_breakfast"></span></div>
            <div class="text-uppercase">Complimentary Continental Breakfast</div>
        </div>
  
  </section>
```

i have just added the -webkit property in front of the keyframes, and also added the -moz property for the firefox browser. These code works fine in chrome, safari and firefox.